# Deleting data directly without refreshing the component in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to delete a post, but it looks like I have to refresh the page everytime. Store is also updating after refresh when I look into the React devtools in Chrome. I need to understand the reason behind this.

So, I have a `UserPosts` component on route like `www.abc.com/profile/jimmy/posts`. This page conatains the user's posts in the form of cards. These have a delete button also.

**UserPosts.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getUserPosts, getCurrentUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Cards from "./Cards"

class UserPosts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
      if (this.props && this.props.userId) {
        this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.userId))
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    const { isFetchingUserPosts, userPosts } = this.props
    return isFetchingUserPosts ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {userPosts &&
          userPosts.map(post => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToPros = state => {
  return {
    isFetchingUserPosts: state.userPosts.isFetchingUserPosts,
    userPosts: state.userPosts.userPosts,
    userId: state.auth.user._id
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToPros)(UserPosts)
```

**Cards.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { deletePost } from "../actions/userActions"

class Cards extends Component {

  handleDelete = (_id) => {
    this.props.dispatch(deletePost(_id))
  }

  render() {
    const { _id, title, description } = this.props.post
    return (
      <div className="card">  
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{border: "1px grey"}}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
              <button className="button is-success">Edit</button>
              <button onClick={() => {this.handleDelete(_id)}} className="button is-success">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {
    nothing: "nothing"
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cards)
```

**deletePost action**

```js
export const deletePost = (id) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
      try {
        const deletedPost = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`)
        dispatch({
          type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS",
          data: deletedPost
        })
      } catch(error) {
        dispatch({
          type: "DELETING_POST_FAILURE",
          data: { error: "Something went wrong" }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**post reducer**

```js
const initialState = {
    isDeletingPost: false,
    isDeletedPost: false,
    deletingError: null,
    postList: []
}


export const post = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "DELETING_POST_START":
            return {
                ...state,
                isDeletingPost: true,
                deletingError: null
        }
        case "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS":
            const filteredPostList = state.postList.filter(post => post._id !== action.data._id )
            return {
                ...state,
                isDeletingPost: false,
                isDeletedPost: true,
                postList: filteredPostList,
                deletingError: null
        }
        case "DELETING_POST_ERROR":
            return {
                ...state,
                isDeletingPost: false,
                deletingError: action.data.error
        }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I just need to know how to solve this issue and why's it not happening as expected. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I have two reducers. Please ignore the above one. Here are the  reducers https://hastebin.com/koqijinabi.coffeescript.

Comment: What do you mean by "have to refresh the page"?  Dispatching actions and updating the store state should cause your component to re-render immediately.  What specifically is happening?

Comment: Have you set up the thunk middleware? Otherwise you can't have action creators that return functions.

Comment: @markerikson i mean i have all the posts and a delete button, so when i click on the delete button, the deleted post should go, and the other remaining posts be seen on the page immediately. In other words, after I click on the delete button and the page should re-render. However, store is updating when i refresh the page. So i guess, it's not re-rendering.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn yes, i have redux-thunk already setup.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `mapState` is wrong:

```js
const mapStateToPros = state => {
  return {
    isFetchingUserPosts: state.userPosts.isFetchingUserPosts,
    userPosts: state.userPosts.userPosts,
    userId: state.auth.user._id
  }
}
```

Your posts state looks like:

```js
const initialState = {
    isDeletingPost: false,
    isDeletedPost: false,
    deletingError: null,
    postList: []
}
```

You don't have `.isFetchingUserPosts` or `.userPosts` in there.  You *do* have `isDeletingPost` and `.postList`.

Fix up your `mapState` so that it matches the actual field names in your state, and this should work.

Comment: I forgot to put the whole reducer code. I am using two reducers, like this. https://hastebin.com/koqijinabi.coffeescript